# Проблема с добавлением некоторых Java классов и файлов в Git

Tags: java, android, android-studio, git, bitbucket

Использую AndroidStudio + Git. В качестве хостинга - bitbucket. Заметил, что не все классы и файлы заливаются на сервер, даже после команды git add. 
Пытался и вручную через консоль, и через встроенные инструменты студии. 
Изменений Git не видит, с его точки зрения - все замечательно. (Нет ни "зеленых", ни "синих" классов).
[image: Не видит изменений]

После очередного git commit все так же, изменений нет никаких.
[image: Нет изменений]

В самом же bitbuckete есть только один из созданных классов, и больше никаких.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Пробовал несколько вариантов решения из данного ресурса, в моем случае ничего не помогло. Остался последний из вариантов - удаление репозитория, затем повторно инициализировать, но не хотелось бы доводить до крайности. Что можете посоветовать?

Comment: проверьте файлы .gitignore. Папки где лежат ваши файлы, не должны присутствовать в нем.

Comment: забыл добавить - .gitignore проверил, там только не нужные файлы

Comment: `git add` не заливает файлы на сервер. Это делает `git push`

Comment: Я имел ввиду, что делал команду git add, пытаясь добавить файлы для следующего коммита, чего сделать не удалось. Разумеется, на сервер заливал командой git push.